# How to use a variable in innerHTML statement to display specific object values

Tags: javascript

I have variables being passed from a button to a function go() in the HTML file. The function go() then calls an external function displayInfo() and passes the variable to it.

The code below displays "undefined". Is it possible to use the countryName string to target the objects instead of the object name?

```
document.getElementById("show-country").innerHTML = countryName.name;
document.getElementById("show-population").innerHTML = countryName.population;
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function go(val)
        {  displayInfo(val); }
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="england" onclick="go(this.value)">
    <input type="button" value="france" onclick="go(this.value)">

    <div>
        <h1 id="show-country"></h1>
        <p id="show-population"></p>
    </div>


    <script src="countries.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

countries.js:

```
function displayInfo (countryName)
{
    var england =
    {
        name :      "England",
        population: "53.01 million"
    };
    var france =
    {
        name :      "France",
        population: "66.9 million"
    };


    document.getElementById("show-country").innerHTML = countryName.name;
    document.getElementById("show-population").innerHTML = countryName.population;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're currently going about it, no. You could store your countries in an object, and then target the objects keys:

```
let countries = {
    england: {
        name :      "England",
        population: "53.01 million"
    },
    france: {
        name :      "France",
        population: "66.9 million"
    }
}
```

Then use bracket notation to display the properties if it exists:

```
if (countries.hasOwnProperty(countryName)) {
    document.getElementById("show-country").innerHTML = countries[countryName].name;
    document.getElementById("show-population").innerHTML = countries[countryName].population;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which may help you

```js
  var countries={
  england :{
    name : "England",
    population: "53.01 million"
  },
 france:{
   name :  "France",
   population: "66.9 million"
 }
};

function displayInfo (countryName){
  document.getElementById("show-country").innerHTML = countries[countryName].name;
  document.getElementById("show-population").innerHTML = countries[countryName].population;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    function go(val)
    {  displayInfo(val); }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="england" onclick="go(this.value)">
    <input type="button" value="france" onclick="go(this.value)">
    <div>
      <h1 id="show-country"></h1>
      <p id="show-population"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="countries.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

In the countryName you just pass the value attribut of the button.
In the javascript function you use countryName.name or population but countryName is only a string.

The solution is :

`function displayInfo (countryName)
{
    var data = null;
    var england =
    {
        name :      "England",
        population: "53.01 million"
    };
    var france =
    {
        name :      "France",
        population: "66.9 million"
    };`

```
if(countryName === "england"){
  data = england;
}
else{
  data = france;
}


document.getElementById("show-country").innerHTML = data.name;
document.getElementById("show-population").innerHTML = data.population;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```js
  var countries={
  england :{
    name : "England",
    population: "53.01 million"
  },
 france:{
   name :  "France",
   population: "66.9 million"
 }
};

function displayInfo (countryName){
  document.getElementById("show-country").innerHTML = countries[countryName].name;
  document.getElementById("show-population").innerHTML = countries[countryName].population;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    function go(val)
    {  displayInfo(val); }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="england" onclick="go(this.value)">
    <input type="button" value="france" onclick="go(this.value)">
    <div>
      <h1 id="show-country"></h1>
      <p id="show-population"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="countries.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).